# How to calculate the distance between two longitudes at different latitudes?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I'm creating a program and I need to know if an object on the globe moves more on the Y axis or on the X axis. To do it, I need to get the distance in meters between two latitudes and two longitudes.

```
// Calculates the distance between two latitudes.
angle = latitude2 - latitude1;
radius = 6378.137 * 1000;
metersPerDegree = (radius * Math.PI * 2 / 360);
print("The distance traveled on the Y axis (latitude) is: " + (angle * metersPerDegree));
```

The problem is that for the **longitude**, I can't use the code above. This is because the circumference of the sphere (in this case, of the Earth) varies as latitude increases or decreases.

```
angle = 89; // Latitude = 89°
print(metersPerDegree * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180)); // 1942.79 meters for each degree of longitude
angle = 57; // Latitude = 57°
print(metersPerDegree * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180)); // 60628.94 meters for each degree of longitude
```

My question is: how do I calculate the longitudinal distance between two coordinates?

Comment: Have you already read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude

Comment: @Joe Yes, but I din't undestand anything and I think that's not what I'd like to know. As you can see on my question, I know how to get the length of a degree of longitude. My problem is getting the longitudinal distance from A to B at different latitudes. Example: A = (78, 45) and B = (34, 56). What is the distance from longitude 45° to longitude 56°? I would know if the latitude was static, but it varies 44 degrees.

Comment: The "longitudinal distance" is not well defined quantity. If you travel to a higher latitude, then travel longitudinally, you would traverse less distance longitudinally than if first traveled longitudinally, then went to the higher latitude.

Comment: @Joe I know that. You are just saying the obvious -_-

Comment: So you know that "the longitudinal distance between two coordinates" is not a well defined quantity, but you are asking how to calculate "the longitudinal distance between two coordinates"?

Comment: I know that this problem is difficult to solve because variation of the length of a degree of longitude. But I believe that it is not impossible, since it is possible to calculate the distance between two coordinates: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/365853/11679204

Comment: I think you want the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)